# Allowing External Invocation of Cloud Run

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create a an API in GCP for a webhook to target. In particular, the event webhook are on Twilio Sendgrid. I need the requests to be authenticated (don't want unauthenticated requests), but I am not sure the correct way to do it.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook-security-features#oauth-client-credentials-flow), if I provide a Client Id and Secret, Sendgrid generates an *access token* from GCP's authentications server (I am guessing this is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token). However, Cloud Run requires an *identity token*. Am I understanding this correctly and if so, is there a way around this?

Comment: The flow that you shared is for the sendgrid OAuth2 access token, not for the Google Cloud access token, isn't it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, that is what I intended to show.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the issue I am having is that it seems like Sendgrid is sending only an OAuth2 access token whereas API Gateway is requiring an identity token. I can't figure out a way to configure my Gateway to accept an access token. If I try, it gives response like

{
"message": "Jwt is not in the form of Header.Payload.Signature with two dots and 3 sections",
"code": 401
}

Do you know a way to configure the Gateway to accept these access tokens that are not Jwt?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I guess as an alternative they provide a key to me. I am wondering if there is some way in the OpenId config to require that key to be present in the header. Do you know anything?

Answer (score -1):

You can't generate a Google Cloud OAuth token from Twilio (Access Token or Identity Token). Your webhook must be publicly available on the internet.

To secure the connection, you can create your own API key if you want, by setting your webhook URL like that

```
https://XXXX.run.app?key=<API KEY>
```

And check the API KEY query param in your Cloud Run. If not match, discard the request.

---

Another solution is to use API Gateway, which is a managed version of ESPv2. I mention that because I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) with ESPv2 but with small change, you will be able to do the same thing on API Gateway.

Comment: with Google Client credentials, Twilio sends a request to get a Google access token. My issue here is that API Gateway seems to require and identity token.

Comment: Twilio can't do that. Twilio generate Twilio access token.

Comment: If I provide GCP client credentials and GCP Oauth token url, aren't they getting a GCP token?

Comment: Twilio can't validate your Google credential, only Google can!

Comment: Correct. Don't they use the credentials to get an access token, then send the access token to my GCP API Gateway where the API Gateway tries to validate it?

Comment: guillaumeblaquiere am I not correct that they are generating a Google access token using the client credentials, passing it in their request to the API Gateway, and that API Gateway is validating that access token via Google OAuth?